# Cooling mat for pets that actually cools?

Tags: cats, dogs, temperature

I'm in the Caribbean and temperatures here are reaching over 100°F. My two cats (a 1-year old and a senior citizen) are hot.

Has anyone had experience with cooling mats? It's a mat that maintains a cooler temperature for when the pet's sleeping.

I bought one some time ago. It was a waste of money.

Comment: For the physics behind it: cooling mats do not cool active. They provide the pets a place to lay down, where temperature differences between body and surrounding can be reduced quicker than when the pet with it's insulating fur walks or lays down on "common" surfaces. So it  an not cool down your cat lower than the surrounding temperature. For my rabbits I use left over floor tiles for the same reason. If you want more active cooling, you can use evaporation. By changing water to vapor it takes energy from the surface, so it "takes" temperature and the surface cools down.

Comment: If you want an active chilling device, they exist -- peltier coolers might be the simplest version -- but of course you need to provide power to them, and the heat they remove (plus the heat wasted in running them) has to go somewhere. I haven't seen one built into a pet bed.

Or you could throw an ice pack in the freezer, wrap that in a towel, and it will provide cooling for a while.

Assuming the cat actually discovers it and decides it's a good idea.

Comment: Generally speaking, cats don't require additional cooling in hot climate, provided ample supply of drinking water and a shady place to lie down is provided. When providing a shady place, make sure it is well ventilated, e.g. not a cat house in the open sun where the inside temperature is much higher than outside. In addition to plenty of fresh water, feeding wet food instead of kibble also helps with fluid intake in hot climate.